Visual Studio Code is adding 5 spaces of indentation for new lines despite all settings being for tabs
I'm using Visual Studio Code with Python and every time I hit enter on a line of code, the next line is indented by 5 spaces. However:

Detect Indentation is OFF
Insert spaces when pressing tab is OFF
Tab size is 4

My settings per the UI are:

But here's what I see. When I pressed enter on my last line of code and then highlighted up, you can see the five spaces. Where are they coming from?


the indent is under the g - do you have any extensions or formatters configured?

I don't know what "under the g" means. I do not have any extensions or formatters, but I may have found a work around as listed below.

Found in another response, comment by user megamorf:

Sometimes VSCode keeps old settings for the currently opened files. In that case open the file and in the bottom right corner click on Spaces and select Convert Indentation to Spaces.

I clicked "tab size:4" in the bottom right which brings up the quickmenu at the top to handle indention including the "convert all space indentation to tabs". After having done that the problem goes away.  Even after closing and reopening the file.
